# Windows 10 What's the keyboard shortcut to quickly toggle Do Not Disturb or Focus Assist?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

What's the keyboard shortcut to quickly turn off all notifications in Windows 10?

I'll be working or showing someone something on my computer and need a way to mute all incoming notifications from the notification center. This is especially important now that Windows 10 allows you to receive your phone's text message notifications in Windows notifications--not to mention Slack, calendar, and email notifications.

Almost all computing platforms I've ever used have a quick way to enable a Do Not Disturb mode (e.g. Android: volume button->bell icon, iPhone: dedicated side switch), so I was surprised when Googling "Windows 10 do not disturb keyboard shortcut" yielded nothing.

I looked at the focus assist settings in Settings -> System -> Focus Assist, but there's nothing there to help turn it on quickly.

The closest I've found is you open the notification sidebar with `Win+a` and click "Focus assist" to toggle between Priority only, Alarm only, and Off. Is this the best Windows 10 can do?

Comment: What 'flavor' of Win10? `Presentation Mode` is available unless you're on `Home`.

Comment: I do have Windows Home. Looked for presentation mode and found "Adjust settings before a presentation." When I clicked on it, I got an error saying "Windows cannot find 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\presentationsettings.exe'. Is Presentation Mode toggleable via keyboard shortcut on other flavors of Windows?

Comment: ... **_unless_** you're on `Home`. It's like Bitlocker, we home users are out of luck,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The closest I've found is you open the notification sidebar with Win+a
>   and click "Focus assist" to toggle between Priority only, Alarm only,
>   and Off. Is this the best Windows 10 can do?

I spent some time with this and yes, for Keystrokes, that is the best you can do with V1909. Future versions may improve.

I just turn all mine OFF to avoid the interruptions. That works best in the end.

There is no keyboard shortcut except the one above for this to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: "Off" would mean missing meetings and not seeing important Slack messages/urgent texts, so can't use that option. I'll hold off accepting for a week or so in case anyone else can provide an answer. Otherwise, I'll accept this. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: You can also turn notifications off just for certain times and that may help you.  These options and the Win A options are about all there are.  Also consider using your smart phone for notifications which will not intrude upon your computer

Comment: You could use an AutoHotkey script to create a dedicated hotkey for it. See for example https://superuser.com/questions/1683042/how-to-assign-a-hotkey-to-enable-disable-focus-assist-on-windows-10-11

Answer (score 7):

I understand that this question is about Windows 10 but if you are in Windows 11 you can accomplish  this in 3 keystrokes:

1. `Windows Key + N` - Opens Notification Center with the "Do not disturb" icon selected (see picture below)
2. `Enter`

[image: Notification Center Flyout]

For more Windows 11 shortcuts see https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-11-keyboard-shortcuts/4c810ff5-7524-4cfe-93bc-f38c893ccf21

Comment: WIndows Key + N opens up my calender view.

Comment: The goat. I've known about `Win + N` opening notifications, but didn't ever notice that the do not disturb button was pre-focused when you do this. @Someguy - Win + N opens calendar yes, but with notification area right above it. I mean I'm pretty sure "N" stands for "Notifications"

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do it entirely on the keyboard.

**First way:**

<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> to focus in the System tray

<kbd>Left arrow</kbd> to move from the fist item in the system tray to the last, which should be the notification area

<kbd>Win Menu</kbd> (right of space and Alt Gr keys) and use the underscored menu shortcuts to open the focus assist menu and select an item.

In english that would be <kbd>F</kbd> for **F**ocus assist, then:
<kbd>O</kbd>ff,
<kbd>P</kbd>riority only
or
<kbd>A</kbd>larms only

**Second way:**

<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to open the Action Center

2 x <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to move to the quick actions

<kbd>Arrow keys</kbd> to select the Focus Assist Quick action.

<kbd>Enter</kbd> to Cycle through the 3 states

Answer (score 1):

See here https://tdalon.blogspot.com/2023/09/ahk-focus-assist.html for a unique solution implemented in AutoHotkey and using UIAutomation.

This allows you to really set the focus mode, not only toggle it.

See code also available in a Gist linked in the blog post:

```
FocusAssist(sInput){

; Open Focus Assist Settings
Run, ms-settings:quiethours

; Wait for WinTitle=Settings
WinWaitActive,Settings

UIA := UIA_Interface()

WinId := WinActive("A")
UIAEl := UIA.ElementFromHandle(WinId) 

Switch sInput
{
Case "f","-": ; Off
    Filter := "AutomationId=Microsoft.QuietHoursProfile.Unrestricted_Button"
Case "p","+": ; Priority Only
    Filter := "AutomationId=Microsoft.QuietHoursProfile.PriorityOnly_Button"
Case "a": ; Alarm Only
    Filter := "AutomationId=Microsoft.QuietHoursProfile.AlarmsOnly_Button"
}

Btn := UIAEl.WaitElementExist(Filter)
Btn.Click()

Send !{f4} ; Close settings window


} ; eofun
```

Answer (score 0):

Right clicking the notification icon [image: notification icon] and pressing `t` satisfies me.

EDIT: Let me check what build version I have but this is what it looks like [image: on right-click notif button]

EDIT 2: Windows 10 Build version "Version 1709 (OS Build 16299.2166)"

Comment: That doesn't do anything on my computer.

Comment: My Windows 10 build number currently is "Version 1709 (OS Build 16299.2166)"

Comment: That is an unsupported build of Windows 10 and should not be used. Build 1909 is the current oldest build still supported in personal editions of Windows 10 (1809 is allowed for Enterprise and Education licenses) and support for it ends May of this year (2020).

Comment: I see. The company issues this machine. Maybe they didn't allow the OS to update and let it be in a state where it has the factory OS built-in. Please ignore this answer.

Comment: Though probably a fine answer at the time, **today** the above menu is now shown as two cascaded menus