# How to assign a hotkey to enable/disable Focus Assist on Windows 10/11?

Tags: windows-10, autohotkey, windows-11, focus-assist

To my surprise, there seems to not be a Windows hotkey for enabling/disabling Focus Assist on Windows 11.

Is there a way to force such a hotkey, even if it requires the use of third-party software (such as AutoHotkey)?

---

**Clarification:** The acceptable solution should not include any use of the mouse in the end result. I.e., I should be able to enable/disable Focus Assist by simply pressing a key or a combination of keys.

Comment: You can enable/disable within the Activity Center.  You can display the Activity Center by using Windows key + A.  Outside of that method or going into Settings there isn't a shortcut specifically to enable or disable Focus Assist[.](https://superuser.com/questions/1527760/windows-10-whats-the-keyboard-shortcut-to-quickly-toggle-do-not-disturb-or-focu)

Comment: You can use RegWrite and RegDelete in AutoHotkey to change or delete the Quiet Hours via the Registry Editor as described [here](https://appuals.com/how-to-change-windows-10-quiet-hours-focus-assist-automatic-rules/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, thank you https://superuser.com/users/192857/fred for nearly getting there ...

`Win + N` then `Shift + Tab` then `Enter` or `Space`

This will:

- EITHER open (and start) a (30 minute) focus session
- OR end the focus session (not pause)

Comment: An excellent solution! For the record, one can combine this with AutoHotKey to create an easier key combination!

Answer (score 2):

[AutoHotkey script](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm), first one I've ever done :)

```
; ^6=Ctrl+6 activates script. #f=Win+F which would take over a builtin hotkey opens Feedback Hub and screenshot
^6::
; Keys sequence: Win+B, Left, Menu/Right-click key, Down 2x, Enter, Down=Priority (2x=Alarm), Enter
; Win+B Sets focus for the Show hidden icons dropdown menu: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/keyboard-shortcuts-in-windows-dcc61a57-8ff0-cffe-9796-cb9706c75eec
Send, #b
Sleep, 500 ; wait 0.5sec since PC's need a moment to bring up menus sometimes
Send, {Left}{AppsKey}
Sleep, 500
Send, {Down 2}{Enter}{Down}{Enter}{Esc} ; Esc closes notifications bar
; Send, {Down 2}{Enter}{Down 2}{Enter} ; uncomment this line for Alarms only then comment above line
return

; Turn off Windows Focus Assist with Ctrl+0
^0::
Send, #b
Sleep, 500
Send, {Left}{AppsKey}
Sleep, 500
Send, {Down 2}{Enter 2}{Esc}
return
; VARIATION2: Win+I, focus assist, Down, Enter, Tab 3x=Priority (4x=Alarm), Spacebar, Alt+F4
; VARIATION3: Win+A, Shift+Tab 3x, Enter, Tab 2x, Down 2x, Right 3x, Enter=Priority Mode, Enter 2x=Alarm
```

Comment: Excellent! I had to edit the steps and the timing a bit, probably because I have edited my taskbar but your solution is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`Windows Key + N` then `Enter` toggles focus sessions on  and off.  See https://superuser.com/a/1761680/192857

Comment: This switches on do not disturb ...  but this was close and I have given a separate answer below ...

Answer (score 1):

The policy setting that controls Toast Notifications is
particularly difficult to undo. It is controlled by the
Local Group Policy Editor at
*User Configuration > Administrative Templates >
Start Menu and Taskbar > Notifications*, policy
"Turn off toast notifications".
It modifies various registry entries, but also several files,
one of whom is in binary format, so not user-modifiable.
This is why a Microsoft utility is required for setting it.

I will give below two commands for enabling and disabling
Toast Notifications.
You may put them in two `.bat` files and assign them hotekeys,
or alternatively use
[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

**Prerequisite**

Download the LGPO utility, the Local Group Policy Object Utility,
from
[Microsoft Security Compliance Toolkit 1.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55319).

When pressing the Download button, select "LGPO.zip" and click
Next to download it.
Unzip the archive to obtain this utility in `LGPO.exe`.

**Input files**

Create two text files as follows (you may use your own file-names):

**1. disable_toast_notifications.txt**

```
User
SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PushNotifications
NoToastApplicationNotification
DWORD:1
```

**2. enable_toast_notifications.txt**

```
User
SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PushNotifications
NoToastApplicationNotification
DWORD:0
```

**Disable Toast Notifications**

Use the following command in Run as Administrator mode:

```
\path\LGPO.exe /t \path\disable_toast_notifications.txt
```

**Enable Toast Notifications**

Use the following command in Run as Administrator mode:

```
\path\LGPO.exe /t \path\enable_toast_notifications.txt
```

For more information see the article
[How to use LGPO.exe to modify lgpo settings (with lgpo examples)](https://www.brookspeppin.com/2018/11/04/modify-local-gpo-examples/).

Comment: Thank you for the post. Is the "Toast Notification" option the same with Focus Assist? I'm asking because when I run the bat file to disable/enable notifications the focus assist button doesn't change. I.e., Either the command does not work or the change is "silent".

Comment: I was assuming that your request was all about notifications, which is what I did. If you need more, what else do you want to do in *Settings  > System > Focus assist*?

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Firstly, if Toast Notifications <=> Focus Assist, then we are talking about the same thing. Secondly, I don't think that this solution works: Running either of these two bat files changes nothing to the behavior of my system and does not alter the Focus Assist button. P.s. Yes, I am using the correct paths and running them as adminstrator.

Comment: You should be looking at *gpedit.msc > User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Start Menu and Taskbar > Notifications > Turn off toast notifications*. Focus Assist is a development of Quiet Hours, intended for avoiding notifications, with the possibility of setting automatic rules for it. Its effect is mainly to set Toast Notifications. As you would like to be able to quickly turn it on and off, mine is a solution with the best effect. It can be extended more, if you really are unsatisfied, but you should really try it first.

Comment: Great, thank you for the clarification. I have experimented with the solution and I can confirm that running `disable_toast_notifications.bat` has disabled all toast notifications which is what I am looking for. HOWEVER `enable_toast_notifications.bat` does not seem to bring the toast notifications back. Can you kindly investigate this and maybe edit your answer? If this is solved I will mark your answer as correct and award the points.

Comment: I found that Gpedit doesn't always update the displayed values. You need to close and relaunch  it to be sure.

Comment: How do I close Gpedit? It does not appear in the list of running processes (Task Manager).

Comment: I just tried it with a test [PowerShell script](https://github.com/Windos/BurntToast/blob/main/Help/New-BurntToastNotification.md) that creates a notification, and it worked well for me several times. Gpedit was not running at all during the test. Please check the above text files, as LGPO is not great on error messages.

Comment: Addendum: Thank you for the solution. After experimenting with it I can confirm that it works and I recommend it to anyone looking to do something similar to my request. However, I have chosen @gregg's solution as the correct one, as it uses Focus Assist which is more versatile than disabling toast notifications altogether.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131064/discussion-between-aventinus-and-harrymc).

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 11:

1. <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> (To open the [Notification Center](https://www.windowscentral.com/whats-new-action-center-windows-11))
2. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> (To select the Focus button)
3. <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Space</kbd> (To activate the Focus button)

This will **toggle** a [Focus mode](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/how-to-use-focus-in-windows-11-cbcc9ddb-8164-43fa-8919-b9a2af072382). In other words, it will either:

- Start a (30-minute) focus session; **or**
- End the focus session (not pause).

On Windows 10:

1. <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> (To open the [Action Center](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/open-use-windows-10-action-center))
2. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> (To select the display brightness)
3. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> (To select the last selected button)
4. <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Space</kbd> (To activate the button)

Notice the caveat on the Windows 10 option: It will active the last used button, which is not necessarily the Focus Assist button. In practice, I find that set of key commands the most useful for toggling Focus Assist on and off throughout a workday. For a more robust solution not dependent on the last selected button, you can do something like this:

1. <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> (To open the [Action Center](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/open-use-windows-10-action-center))
2. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> (To select the display brightness)
3. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> (To select the last selected button)
4. <kbd>End</kbd> (To select last button in presentation order)
5. <kbd>← Left Arrow</kbd> (To select the second-to-last button in presentation order)
6. <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Space</kbd> (To activate the button)

However, this still depends on the presentation order of the buttons, which can be easily configured by right clicking anywhere in the Action Center, and activating the "Edit" menu option. You could minimize the number of keystrokes by moving Focus Assist to the first or last position.

The above methods Windows 10 methods will **cycle** [Focus Assist](https://www.howtogeek.com/349829/how-to-use-focus-assist-do-not-disturb-mode-on-windows-10/) modes. In other words, they will either:

- Enable Focus Assist, showing priority notifications only; **or**
- Enable Focus Assist, showing alarm notification only; **or**
- Disable Focus Assist.

Comment: I'm not sure if the original question needs editing but the point is to have *one* hotkey to enable/disable Focus Mode. A series of hotkeys, especially when they are 3+, beats the purpose, I might as well use the mouse instead. But thanks for sharing.

Comment: As you have learned you can combine these steps into one hotkey with AutoHotkey

Answer (score 0):

See here an improved solution based on UIAutomation https://tdalon.blogspot.com/2023/09/ahk-focus-assist.html

It has the advantage not only to toggle the focus mode but really set it as you command it.